# ActiveMQ Apollo AMQP NullPointerException

Tags: activemq-classic, apollo

Getting following exception while trying to post a Java object. Any pointers are appreciated.

```
2015-12-26 23:06:32,876 | WARN  | stackref=151df5b0a0f
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.QueueEntry$Swapped.swapped_in(QueueEntry.scala:809)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.QueueEntry$Swapped$$anonfun$swap_in$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply$mcV$sp(QueueEntry.scala:764)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.util.DeferringDispatched$$anon$1.run(Dispatched.scala:38)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.util.DeferringDispatched$$anonfun$dispatch_queue_task_source$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Dispatched.scala:45)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.util.DeferringDispatched$$anonfun$dispatch_queue_task_source$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Dispatched.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:309)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.util.DeferringDispatched$$anonfun$dispatch_queue_task_source$1.apply$mcV$sp(Dispatched.scala:45)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.package$$anon$4.run(hawtdispatch.scala:357)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.HawtCustomDispatchSource$1.run(HawtCustomDispatchSource.java:127)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.SerialDispatchQueue.run(SerialDispatchQueue.java:100)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.pool.SimpleThread.run(SimpleThread.java:77)
```

Answer (score 3):

There has been little to no development on ActiveMQ Apollo in quite some time and doubt there will be any to come.  You should use ActiveMQ 5 or try out ActiveMQ Artemis to see if that meets your needs.