# Apache Apollo on Ubuntu 14.04 - Can not connect to Websocket (Thread issue?)

Tags: multithreading, apache, ubuntu, jvm, apollo

I deployed MyBroker service on Ubuntu 14.04 Virtual Machine and get the following logs:
apollo.log:

```
    2016-03-07 13:52:28,301 | INFO  | java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer | 1535101acf6
2016-03-07 13:52:28,301 | INFO  | java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer | 1535101acf8
2016-03-07 13:52:28,302 | INFO  | java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer | 1535101acfa
2016-03-07 13:52:28,302 | INFO  | java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer | 1535101acfc
2016-03-07 13:52:28,303 | INFO  | java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer | 1535101acfe
2016-03-07 13:52:28,303 | INFO  | java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer | 1535101ad00
2016-03-07 13:52:28,303 | INFO  | java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer | 1535101ad02
2016-03-07 13:52:37,923 | INFO  | java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer | 1535101ad04
2016-03-07 13:53:07,938 | INFO  | java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer | 1535101ad06
2016-03-07 13:53:27,963 | INFO  | java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer | 1535101ad08
```

connection.log

```
2016-03-07 13:53:22,817 connected: local:/127.0.0.1:61613, remote:/127.0.0.1:53221
2016-03-07 13:53:22,825 connected: local:/127.0.0.1:61613, remote:/127.0.0.1:53222
2016-03-07 13:53:22,847 connected: local:/127.0.0.1:61613, remote:/127.0.0.1:53222
2016-03-07 13:53:22,852 connected: local:/127.0.0.1:61613, remote:/127.0.0.1:53221
2016-03-07 13:53:27,045 disconnected: local:/127.0.0.1:61613, remote:/127.0.0.1:53222
2016-03-07 13:53:27,963 Shutting connection '/127.0.0.1:53221'  down due to: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
2016-03-07 13:53:27,964 disconnected: local:/127.0.0.1:61613, remote:/127.0.0.1:53221
```

stacktrace.log

```
2016-03-04 14:31:40,305 | WARN  | stackref=153416c3084
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 32
    at org.fusesource.mqtt.codec.SUBSCRIBE.decode(SUBSCRIBE.java:65)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.mqtt.MqttSession.on_transport_command(MqttSession.java:334)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.mqtt.MqttSession$3.call(MqttSession.java:142)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.util.UnitFn1.apply(Scala2JavaHelper.scala:41)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.mqtt.MqttProtocolHandler.on_transport_command(MqttProtocolHandler.java:377)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.BrokerConnection.on_transport_command(Connection.scala:144)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.Connection$$anon$1.onTransportCommand(Connection.scala:71)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.jetty.WebSocketTransportFactory$WebSocketTransport.drain_inbound(WebSocketTransportFactory.scala:480)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.jetty.WebSocketTransportFactory$WebSocketTransport$$anonfun$onMessage$1.apply$mcV$sp(WebSocketTransportFactory.scala:403)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.package$$anon$4.run(hawtdispatch.scala:357)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.SerialDispatchQueue.run(SerialDispatchQueue.java:100)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.SerialDispatchQueue.run(SerialDispatchQueue.java:100)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.pool.SimpleThread.run(SimpleThread.java:77)
2016-03-04 14:31:44,370 | WARN  | stackref=153416c3088
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 32
    at org.fusesource.mqtt.codec.SUBSCRIBE.decode(SUBSCRIBE.java:65)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.mqtt.MqttSession.on_transport_command(MqttSession.java:334)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.mqtt.MqttSession$3.call(MqttSession.java:142)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.util.UnitFn1.apply(Scala2JavaHelper.scala:41)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.mqtt.MqttProtocolHandler.on_transport_command(MqttProtocolHandler.java:377)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.BrokerConnection.on_transport_command(Connection.scala:144)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.Connection$$anon$1.onTransportCommand(Connection.scala:71)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.jetty.WebSocketTransportFactory$WebSocketTransport.drain_inbound(WebSocketTransportFactory.scala:480)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.jetty.WebSocketTransportFactory$WebSocketTransport$$anonfun$onMessage$1.apply$mcV$sp(WebSocketTransportFactory.scala:403)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.package$$anon$4.run(hawtdispatch.scala:357)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.SerialDispatchQueue.run(SerialDispatchQueue.java:100)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.SerialDispatchQueue.run(SerialDispatchQueue.java:100)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.pool.SimpleThread.run(SimpleThread.java:77)
2016-03-07 08:47:06,569 | WARN  | stackref=153416c320c
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2016-03-07 08:47:07,227 | WARN  | stackref=153416c320e
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2016-03-07 09:35:08,660 | WARN  | stackref=153416c3319
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.DeliveryProducerRoute$$anonfun$unbind$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Router.scala:258)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.DeliveryProducerRoute$$anonfun$unbind$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Router.scala:256)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filterNot$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:274)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filterNot$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:274)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:264)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:309)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:263)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterNot(TraversableLike.scala:274)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filterNot(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.DeliveryProducerRoute$$anonfun$unbind$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$4.apply(Router.scala:256)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.DeliveryProducerRoute$$anonfun$unbind$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$4.apply(Router.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filterNot$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:274)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filterNot$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:274)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:264)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:309)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:263)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterNot(TraversableLike.scala:274)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filterNot(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.DeliveryProducerRoute$$anonfun$unbind$1.apply$mcV$sp(Router.scala:251)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.util.DeferringDispatched$$anon$1.run(Dispatched.scala:38)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.util.DeferringDispatched$$anonfun$dispatch_queue_task_source$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Dispatched.scala:45)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.util.DeferringDispatched$$anonfun$dispatch_queue_task_source$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Dispatched.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:309)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.util.DeferringDispatched$$anonfun$dispatch_queue_task_source$1.apply$mcV$sp(Dispatched.scala:45)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.package$$anon$4.run(hawtdispatch.scala:357)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.HawtCustomDispatchSource$1.run(HawtCustomDispatchSource.java:127)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.SerialDispatchQueue.run(SerialDispatchQueue.java:100)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.pool.SimpleThread.run(SimpleThread.java:77)
2016-03-07 09:37:13,687 | WARN  | stackref=153416c334d
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2016-03-07 09:37:14,493 | WARN  | stackref=153416c334f
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2016-03-07 09:37:15,274 | WARN  | stackref=153416c3351
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2016-03-07 09:37:16,555 | WARN  | stackref=153416c3353
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2016-03-07 09:38:49,275 | WARN  | stackref=153416c335f
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2016-03-07 09:38:50,234 | WARN  | stackref=153416c3361
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2016-03-07 09:38:50,990 | WARN  | stackref=153416c3363
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2016-03-07 09:38:51,752 | WARN  | stackref=153416c3365
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2016-03-07 09:38:52,515 | WARN  | stackref=153416c3367
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2016-03-07 10:48:21,306 | WARN  | stackref=1535072b8fc
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 80
    at org.fusesource.mqtt.codec.SUBSCRIBE.decode(SUBSCRIBE.java:65)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.mqtt.MqttSession.on_transport_command(MqttSession.java:334)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.mqtt.MqttSession$3.call(MqttSession.java:142)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.util.UnitFn1.apply(Scala2JavaHelper.scala:41)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.mqtt.MqttProtocolHandler.on_transport_command(MqttProtocolHandler.java:377)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.BrokerConnection.on_transport_command(Connection.scala:144)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.Connection$$anon$1.onTransportCommand(Connection.scala:71)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.jetty.WebSocketTransportFactory$WebSocketTransport.drain_inbound(WebSocketTransportFactory.scala:480)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.jetty.WebSocketTransportFactory$WebSocketTransport$$anonfun$onMessage$1.apply$mcV$sp(WebSocketTransportFactory.scala:403)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.package$$anon$4.run(hawtdispatch.scala:357)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.SerialDispatchQueue.run(SerialDispatchQueue.java:100)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.SerialDispatchQueue.run(SerialDispatchQueue.java:100)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.pool.SimpleThread.run(SimpleThread.java:77)
2016-03-07 10:51:57,043 | WARN  | stackref=1535072b916
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 80
    at org.fusesource.mqtt.codec.SUBSCRIBE.decode(SUBSCRIBE.java:65)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.mqtt.MqttSession.on_transport_command(MqttSession.java:334)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.mqtt.MqttSession$3.call(MqttSession.java:142)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.util.UnitFn1.apply(Scala2JavaHelper.scala:41)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.mqtt.MqttProtocolHandler.on_transport_command(MqttProtocolHandler.java:377)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.BrokerConnection.on_transport_command(Connection.scala:144)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.Connection$$anon$1.onTransportCommand(Connection.scala:71)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.jetty.WebSocketTransportFactory$WebSocketTransport.drain_inbound(WebSocketTransportFactory.scala:480)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.jetty.WebSocketTransportFactory$WebSocketTransport$$anonfun$onMessage$1.apply$mcV$sp(WebSocketTransportFactory.scala:403)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.package$$anon$4.run(hawtdispatch.scala:357)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.SerialDispatchQueue.run(SerialDispatchQueue.java:100)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.SerialDispatchQueue.run(SerialDispatchQueue.java:100)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.pool.SimpleThread.run(SimpleThread.java:77)
2016-03-07 13:30:06,035 | WARN  | stackref=1535101abf7
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 32
    at org.fusesource.mqtt.codec.SUBSCRIBE.decode(SUBSCRIBE.java:65)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.mqtt.MqttSession.on_transport_command(MqttSession.java:334)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.mqtt.MqttSession$3.call(MqttSession.java:142)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.util.UnitFn1.apply(Scala2JavaHelper.scala:41)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.mqtt.MqttProtocolHandler.on_transport_command(MqttProtocolHandler.java:377)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.BrokerConnection.on_transport_command(Connection.scala:144)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.Connection$$anon$1.onTransportCommand(Connection.scala:71)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.jetty.WebSocketTransportFactory$WebSocketTransport.drain_inbound(WebSocketTransportFactory.scala:480)
    at org.apache.activemq.apollo.broker.jetty.WebSocketTransportFactory$WebSocketTransport$$anonfun$onMessage$1.apply$mcV$sp(WebSocketTransportFactory.scala:403)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.package$$anon$4.run(hawtdispatch.scala:357)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.SerialDispatchQueue.run(SerialDispatchQueue.java:100)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.SerialDispatchQueue.run(SerialDispatchQueue.java:100)
    at org.fusesource.hawtdispatch.internal.pool.SimpleThread.run(SimpleThread.java:77)
```

My assumption is that the virtual machine with Ubuntu 14.04 (and 1,5 GB RAM) can not handle all the services (Running also other servies like a Tomcat on the same machine) - Someone got an idea based on the posted logfiles? (I only see a NullPointException for the Threads in the stacktrace.log)

Comment: Switch to another Message Broker? like Artemis or ActiveMQ ?

Answer (score 0):

[Apollo activemq AMQP NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474791/apollo-activemq-amqp-nullpointerexception?rq=1) This seems to be the Same Question with the answer I already assumed:

Apollo Developers moved on.

"You should use ActiveMQ 5 or try out ActiveMQ Artemis" https://stackoverflow.com/users/375722/tim-bish